# Access SQL UPDATE with a correlated sub query on a single table

Tags: ms-access, sql-update, subquery, correlated

I have a table with a grid reference string, a year number and a total number (HectadGridRef, YYYY and TotalRecordsAllSpecies). I have added a column, FiveYearTotalRecords. I want to update the new column with values from adjacent years (two years before and after) so that with further processing, I can handle a five year rolling window.

I have tried this on a test version of the table:

```
UPDATE tblYRAllSp5yeartest01 AS XX  
 SET FiveYearTotalRecords = (SELECT SUM (ZZ.TotalRecordsAllSpecies) FROM tblYRAllSp5yeartest01 AS ZZ  
 WHERE (ZZ.HectadGridRef = XX.HectadGridRef)  
   AND (ZZ.YYYY > (XX.YYYY - 3))  
   AND (ZZ.YYYY < (XX.YYYY + 3)));
```

but I get the message "Operation must use an updateable query".

I suspect that the problem is that I am trying to update a table that is already open (by the sub query). Is that the case? Is there any way around it other than making a copy of the table and pointing the sub query at that instead?

[Edit:  I have tried it with a copy of the table and I still get the same message, so I can't think where the problem is. As far as I can see, I have appropriate permissions to the whole database].

Comment: Access considers the query not updateable because it includes a subquery.  The identity of the subquery table is not the issue; any subquery in an `UPDATE` would trigger the same complaint.  See whether [DSum](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/dsum-function-08f8450e-3bf6-45e2-936f-386056e61a32), instead of the subquery, will give you what you want.

Comment: Why do you need to store those sums instead of calculating them when needed in a `SELECT` query?

Comment: @HansUp - Presumably this is an Access restriction, since I have seen examples of UPDATE with a subquery in non-Access SQL - admittedly only with a second table used in the subquery.
I have looked at DSum (thanks for the suggestion) but I would still need to refer to what is in effect the outer query since the DSum criteria would be dynamic, relative to each row in the outer query ... as I understand it at least ... and I'm not sure that is possible.

Comment: @HansUp - Regarding calculating the sums when needed, the rolling "year windows" are preparation for later analysis, ie calculating abundance percentages between species in various hectads over time. Rather than attempting everything in one hit, it sits more comfortably with me to do it in stages.  I have chosen to use SELECT INTO a new table, with the same correlated subquery; so far, that is giving what I want.